# Using the same .com and .net domain - SEO Impact?

Tags: seo, domains

I have a client who has the `.com` and `.net` of their domain. They would like each domain to have content targeted for a different application. Let me explain:

domain-abc.com will contain the services that are paid and provided by the company.

domain-abc.net will be the community portion of the site that contains forums and other topics. All content for the .net domain will be provided for free.

My question is this: Is it better to keep everything on one domain (either .com or .net) vs splitting the site onto two domains for SEO reasons? Or does it has little impact on SEO as long as I don't duplicate content across both domains?

Note: Both the .com and .net are identical names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal and quite common. A good example are cable companies who tend to use the .com as their corporate website and the .net for their consumer services like email.

Comment: Also note that WordPress do the same with .com and .org domains.